# How to render to an offscreen buffer

Tags: c++, mfc

I want to render to an offscreen buffer to avoid flickering in my MFC application. But for now, I simply want to fill an offscreen buffer with some color (red) and copy its content to the screen buffer. The sample code does not work: the window is white instead of red.

```
void CRenderWindow::OnPaint() // CRenderWindow is derived from CDialog
{
  CRect clientRect;
  GetClientRect(&clientRect);

  // Screen DC
  CPaintDC dc(this);

  // Render to offscreen buffer
  CDC offscreenDC;
  offscreenDC.CreateCompatibleDC(&dc);
  CBitmap offscreenBuffer;
  offscreenBuffer.CreateCompatibleBitmap(&offscreenDC, clientRect.Width(), clientRect.Height());
  CBitmap *pOldBitmap = offscreenDC.SelectObject(&offscreenBuffer);

  // Fill the bitmap buffer tied to the offscreenDC with red

  COLORREF clearColor = RGB(255, 0, 0);
  offscreenDC.FillSolidRect(&clientRect, clearColor);

  // Copy the offscreen buffer's content into the screen buffer
  dc.BitBlt(clientRect.left, clientRect.top,         // Destination x&y
            clientRect.Width(), clientRect.Height(), // Source and destination w&h
            &offscreenDC,                            // Source DC
            clientRect.left, clientRect.top,         // Source x&y
            SRCCOPY);
  return;
}
```

I have overridden `OnEraseBkgnd` like so:

```
BOOL CRenderWindow::OnEraseBkgnd(CDC* pDC)
{
    //return CDialog::OnEraseBkgnd(pDC);
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: You must change `CreateCompatibleBitmap(&offscreenDC, ...)` to `CreateCompatibleBitmap(&dc, ...)` because using `offscreenDC` as the argument will create black & white bitmap.

Comment: Any reason not to use `CMemDC` which does buffering anyway?

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Thanks it worked!

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I found code samples that "manually" created the offscreen buffer, so I wanted to write my own code to make sure I understand.

Comment: Possible optimization: create a memory DC only as large as the update rectangle (`dc.m_ps.rcPaint`).

Comment: [CreateCompatibleBitmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createcompatiblebitmap#remarks): *"When a memory device context is created, it initially has a 1-by-1 monochrome bitmap selected into it. If this memory device context is used in `CreateCompatibleBitmap`, the bitmap that is created is a monochrome bitmap. **To create a color bitmap, use the `HDC` that was used to create the memory device context**, as shown in the following code [...]."*